# Custom product template Magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, template, product-images

I'm using Magento 1.9.

If I add a custom option to a product, the thumbnail images for that product no longer appear on the product view page, and you cannot view images 2,3,4, etc  Only the main image is displayed.

i.e. it looks like there's a different product page template being applied for any product where a custom option has been added.

Can anyone advise how to ensure the default product template is being used?

Unless of course, anyone can advise if the custom option is somehow causing an error which is making the thumbnails disappear.

Thanks

Comment: Could be an unexpected result of using a theme. Have you toggles template hints on and off to work out what's what? https://github.com/MagePsycho/MagePsycho_Easypathhints

Comment: I can now add that the error occurs when adding a specific custom option, (the dropdown).  Other types of custom options are fine.  I've worked around this problem by not choosing the dropdown,  Instead I used checkboxes. I would love to know how to solve the original issue.